# Upload file to Azure Blob from HTML webpage (C#)?

Tags: c#, azure, file-upload, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to figure out how to take a file from an html form and save it to my Azure Blob storage. I have found many posts about doing this for JavaScript but I am trying to do it via C#. One source I found said to do

`using (YourFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream((FileStream)YourFileUpload.PostedFile.InputStream);
}`

but `PostedFile` does not exist in the `HttpPostedFileBase` object.

The code I have built out so far is

```
    public static int UploadFile(string FileName, HttpPostedFileBase UploadedFile, int ExistingFileID = 0)
    {
        var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["StorageConnectionString"].ToString());
        var BlobClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var Container = BlobClient.GetContainerReference("ffinfofiles");
        var BlobBlock = Container.GetBlockBlobReference(FileName);
        var FileExtension = Path.GetExtension(UploadedFile.FileName.ToLower());

        using (UploadedFile.InputStream)
        {
            BlobBlock.UploadFromStream((FileStream)UploadedFile.InputStream);
        }
```

but when I run this I get the error:

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.Web.HttpInputStream' to type 'System.IO.FileStream'.`

What method do I need to do so I can upload the file to the Azure Blob?

Comment: [Here](https://gist.github.com/crowcoder/de113d8c4ae50a9594e7) is a Gist of various azure blob operations - may be of use to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not try to cast `UploadedFile.InputStream` to a `FileStream`. `CloudBlockBlob.UploadFromStream` requires a `Stream` object, so it should be able to work directly with `UploadedFile.InputStream`.

Comment: Thank you, removing the cast fixed the error. Now to figure out how to display the blob as an image file inside another page. O the fun of cloud storage.

Comment: @MatthewVerstraete check out my other comment, that Gist demonstrates creating a src URL for an image.